# Does phantom support materialised view?

Tags: scala, cassandra, phantom-dsl

I was digging the web and APIs for couple of hours and I can't seem to find the proper info on this subject. (it is really weird since phantom is advertised as up to date in terms of features with the newest cassandra) If phantom does support materialised view where can I find more info about it and how to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the project lead on phantom so I should know. Materialised views are something we are looking to bring in and the current incomplete implementation is being tested and made ready for prime time.

I can definitely understand it's not fun for a library not to support a feature you are after, we have just been really really busy working on some really cool stuff we are about to launch, e.g phantom-spark, phantom-migrations, and more.

Follow us on Twitter, or subscribe to the newsletter/GitHub follow, and you will be notified automatically once materialised views support is available.